# Get info from table with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to get the information of the specs for this site:

```
http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_1520-5760.php
```

Ideally I would have a hash like this:

```
{'General' => ['2G Network' => 'GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - all versions', 
               '3G Network' => 'HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100 - RM-937, RM-939, RM-940',
               '4G Network' => 'LTE 800 / 900 / 1800 / 2100 / 2600 - RM-937',
               ...
 'Body' => ['Dimensions' =>...
}
```

I have done this so far:

```
results = {}
tables = html.css('#specs-list table')
tables.each do |table|
  category_key = table.css('th').text
  results[category_key] = []
  rows = table.css('tr')

  rows.each do |row|
    spec_key = row.css('.ttl').text
    spec_content = row.css('.nfo').text
    results[category_key] << {spec_key => spec_content}
  end
end
```

The problem is that, for example for 3G Network, there are two rows, and I am not sure how to get them under the 3G Network index in my Hash.

This is the part that is complicated to me:

```html
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="8" scope="row">General</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">2G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - all versions</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">3G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100 - RM-937, RM-939, RM-940</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 - RM-938</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Notice the row `<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>`, it's actually not a new specification category, but the continuation of the previous one. So, ideally it would go into the previous one.

The problem is that in another part of the HTML (when defining the main category Battery), there is this code:

```html
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="4" scope="row">Battery</th>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">Non-removable Li-Ion 3400 mAh battery (BV-4BW)</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=stand-by-time">Stand-by</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Up to 768 h (2G) / Up to 768 h (3G)</td>
</tr><tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, it starts with an empty `<td>`, and this one should not go to the previous one.

I am not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: I think you should check `spec_key` and if it is empty merge `spec_content` with content of previous `spec_key`.

Comment: You need to supply a summarized/small example of the HTML you are trying to parse. Don't ask us to go to that site and summarize it for you.

Comment: you are completely right. I have added the particular HTML code that is causing me some trouble.

Comment: There are no `tbody` tags in the HTML from that site. Be careful when using the source you see in a browser, as it is often massaged by the browser to be "correct". That can really throw off attempts to parse a page.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to check if the `spec_key` is empty. In that case you should append the results to the previous `spec_key`. The only catch here is that you should watch out for the `&nbsp;` charachter. Here is a slightly changed version of your code:

```
results = {}
tables = html.css('#specs-list table')
tables.each do |table|
  category_key = table.css('th').text
  rows = table.css('tr')
  current_spec_key = nil
  category_results = {}
  rows.each do |row|
    spec_key = row.css('.ttl').text.gsub("\u00a0",' ').strip #replace &nbsp; with space
    spec_content = row.css('.nfo').text
    if spec_key.empty?
      category_results[current_spec_key] << ", #{spec_content}"
    else
      current_spec_key = spec_key
      category_results[current_spec_key] = spec_content
    end
  end
  results[category_key] = category_results
end
```

Comment: Nikos, good approach. However, when doing this, I would have a problem in the Battery section. Notice that it starts with an empty <td>, and if I would put it in the previous one, it would be wrong..

Comment: It depends on how you want to represent the case without a spec key. In the simple case where you are fine with something like {"" => "Non-removable..."} you can change the first `if` to `if spec_key.empty? && !current_spec_key.nil?`. If you need a special handling of the first time you find an empty key you can change the first `if` to `if current_spec_key.nil? && spec_key.empty?` and then add an `elsif` and `else` for the other two cases.